# ASP.NET MVC: jQuery UI Autocomplete incorrectly showing all entries

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311447/autocomplete-from-database-in-mvc-5) and studied the mistakes and the example that should work. After that I tried to build it on my own, autcomplete works, but it always shows all entries instead of only that entries that match with the search in the database.

So here is controller code that returns the data for my autocomplete function:

```
public JsonResult AutoCompleteCustomer(string suggestion)
        {
            var data = db.Customers.Where(s => suggestion == null || s.Name.ToLower().Contains(suggestion.ToLower())).Select(x => new { id = x.CustomerID, value = x.CustomerName }).Take(20).ToList();

            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

My code for the autocomplete jQuery UI Feature:

```
<script>
    $("#CustomerName").autocomplete({
        source: "/Customer/AutoCompleteCustomer",
        minLength: 3
    })
</script>
```

The TextBox in the view that should have autocomplete:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerName)
```

If you need any more code or information, please let me know and I will provide it as soon as possible. Thanks!

Comment: The parameter should be `string term`, not `string suggestion`. And remove`suggestion == null ||` from the query. And I assume `return Json(daten,` is a typo (its `data`)

Comment: As always, you caught all my mistakes, thanks! you're awesome! :) and yeah it was a typo, data is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller action has the wrong parameter name it, should be `term`:

```
public JsonResult AutoCompleteCustomer(string term)
    {
        var data = db.Customers.Where(s => term== null || s.Name.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())).Select(x => new { id = x.CustomerID, value = x.CustomerName }).Take(20).ToList();

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Because it is incorrect at the moment it will always be NULL which is why your autocomplete is working but always returning all results as this criteria `suggestion == null` is always true.

If you really wanted to stick with `suggestion` as your controller parameter, you would need to explicitly define this in the AJAX configuration:

```
<script>
    $("#CustomerName").autocomplete({
        source: "/Customer/AutoCompleteCustomer",
        data: { suggestion: request.term },
        minLength: 3
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your code snippet and your explanation, it showed my where my mistake was and that I need to spend more time in reading the documentation to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: just update to remove the == null nonsense... voted up tho.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = (from Customers in db.Customers Where s.Name.ToLower().Contains(suggestion.ToLower()) select  new { id = Customers.CustomerID, value = Customers.CustomerName }).ToList().Take(20);
```

try this