# jquery autocompletion select event, show data from action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

On select event autocompletion, I want to call an JsonResult action in my controller to show data from the database.

function JS

```
select: function (e, i) {
                $("#idp").val(i.item.val);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'Post',
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: '/controller/action/',
                    data: "{ 'id': '" + i.item.val + "'}",
                    success: function (data) {
                        // code to put here//
                        $("#mydiv").html(data);
                    }

                })
            },
```

Comment: What is your question?  Also, we probably need to see the structure of `data`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311447/autocomplete-from-database-in-mvc-5

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

my action

```
public ActionResult ListObject(int? idpatient)
    {
         return PartialView(MyList);
    }
```

My view

```
@model IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Object> table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IdNumber)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Phone)
    </th>
    <th>
       Actions
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Phone)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

i have an autocompletion filed , i want on slect event , call my action and fill the view with data